# Nested snapshot listeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Google Firestore for my iOS app built in Swift/SwiftUI and would like to implement the Snapshot listeners feature to my app.

I want to list all documents in `debts` collection in realtime by using snapshot listeners. Every document in this collection has subcollection `debtors`, which I want to get in realtime for each `debts` document as well. Each document in `debtors` has field `userId`, which refers to DocumentID in `users` collection which I would also love to have realtime connection on (for example when user changes his name I would love to see it instantly in the debt entity inside the list). This means I must initialize 2 more snapshot listeners for each document in `debts` collection. I'm concerned that this is too many opened connections once I have like 100 debts in the list. I can't come up with no idea apart from doing just one time fetches.

Have anyone of you ever dealt with this kind of nested snapshot listeners? Do I have a reason to worry?

This is my Firestore db

```
Debts
 document
  - description
  - ...
  - debtors (subcollection)
    - userId
    - amount
    - ...

Users
 document
   - name
   - profileImage
   - email
```

I uploaded this gist where you can see how I operate with Firestore right now.

https://gist.github.com/michalpuchmertl/6a205a66643c664c46681dc237e0fb5d

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need individual listeners for the documents in the `debtors` subcollection. Why can't you listen to the entire `debtors` collection for the user? Or with a query to the `debtors` that have the specific `UID` that you're interested in.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I can (and want to) listen to the entire `debtors` subcollection, but (and correct me if I am wrong) I have to set a new listener for this `debtors` collection per `debt` document since every `debt` has its own `debtors` subcollection. In the list eventually I want each item to have realtime data about `debts/{document}`, `debts/{document}/debtors` and `users/{uid}`. I can’t imagine any other way to acquire all this information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all `debtors` documents anywhere in the database with a given value for `userId`, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to do so.

In Swift that'd look like:

```
db.collectionGroup("debtors").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: "uidOfTheUser").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    // ...
}
```

This will read from any collection name `debtors`. You'll have to add the index for this yourself, and set up the proper security rules. Both of those are documented in the link I included above.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not explain myself enough. Let me show you part of my code so you can understand better. https://gist.github.com/michalpuchmertl/6a205a66643c664c46681dc237e0fb5d Thank you so much for helping me solve this, appreciate it!